# PHP email text to gmail account

Tags: php, email, forms, gmail

Is there some way I can take text (retrieved from a form), and email it to my gmail account? I can also have the user enter their email address, and a subject. Or if not is there a better way to have users send me a message? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend that you use [PHP Mailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/) this program will take care of all of the message construction and works well with Gmail.  There is also sample code included for Gmail.

Comment: This is safer and easier way to send email than the raw mail functions. Great suggestion!

Comment: Only porblem was replying or from didn't work, but it doesn't matter, I just add the email address to reply to to the start of the body.

Answer (score 4):

Use [`mail`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) function to send email to specific address:

```
$subject = $_REQUEST['subject'];
$message = $_REQUEST['message'];
mail("your@gmail.com", $subject, $message);
```

But please don't take `$to` parameter from form, otherwise your script will be used for spamming.

Comment: $to will always be my gmail account.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on what Ivan wrote to add users email as sender:

```
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$from    = $_POST['from'];

// the sender email must be cleaned of mime header injection
$from = preg_replace_all("/[\r\n]+/", '', $from);

mail("your@gmail.com", $subject, $message, "from:$from\n");
```

This makes it easier to reply. However, you could just append their email address in the message body.

Comment: The "from" is just a plain email address, like 'name@domain.tld', where would these 'mime headers' come frome?

Comment: The email address is a part of the mime message, just like how an email embedded in HTML becomes part of the HTML. So an email like: <i>user@example.com</i> becomes italic in HTML if not escaped of HTML entities. For mime, it is simple, just escape or remove \n.

Comment: Eg: the email user@example.com\nbcc:spam@example.com will send spam to spam@example.com